# How can I convert from Gregorian Calendar to Unix Time, in Java?

Tags: java, methods, gregorian-calendar, unix-timestamp

I am in need of a method to convert GregorianCalendar Object to Unix Time (i.e. a long). Also need a method to convert Unix Time (long) back to GregorianCalendar Object. Are there any methods out there that does this? If not, then how can I do it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Link to GregorianCalendar Class --> http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The methods `getTimeInMillis()` and `setTimeInMillis(long)` will let you get and set the time in milliseconds, which is the unix time multiplied by 1000.  You will have to adjust manually since unix time does not include milliseconds - only seconds.

```
long unixTime = gregCal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
gregCal.setTimeInMillis(unixTime * 1000);
```

*Aside*: If you use dates a lot in your application, especially if you are converting dates or using multiple time zones, I would highly recommend using the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.  It is very complete and quite a bit more natural to understand than the Calendar system that comes with Java.

Comment: The `time` method in Unix C programming returns a whole number of seconds.  It always has.  There is another method `utime` which uses a struct with two longs: one for seconds and one for microseconds.

Comment: Thanks. A `setTimeInMillis` was about the last I would have looked for. Because in Java 1.0 they had the great idea of non-mutable-instances (String, Date, Integer, Long etc. pp) and would not have expected that in 1.1 they given up on the best idea the java designer ever had.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [GregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) and [GregorianCalendar.SetTimeInMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis%28long%29) will let you get and set long values the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the setTimeInMillis and getTimeInMillis functions: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.getTimeInMillis() should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myGregCal.toZonedDateTime().toEpochSecond()                     // Convert from troublesome legacy `GregorianCalendar` to modern `ZonedDateTime`.
```

And going the other direction…

```
GregorianCalendar.from(                                         // Convert from modern `ZonedDateTime` to troublesome legacy class `GregorianCalendar`.
    Instant.ofEpochSecond( yourCountOfWholeSecondsSinceEpoch )  // Moment in UTC.
        .atZone(                                                // Apply `ZoneId` to `Instant` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.
            ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
        )
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The other Answers are correct and short. But, FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9.

So here is how to convert and use the modern classes instead for your problem.

## java.time

Convert from the legacy class `GregorianCalendar` to the modern class `ZonedDateTime`. Call new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregCal.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

And going the other direction…

```
GregorianCalendar myGregCal = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

If by [“Unix time”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) you meant a count of whole seconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, then call `toEpochSecond`.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond() ;
```

If you meant a count of milliseconds since 1970 started in UTC, then extract an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Now [ask for the count of milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--).

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMill() ;
```

Keep in mind that asking for either whole seconds or [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) may involve data loss. The `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` both resolve to nanoseconds. So any [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) or nanoseconds that may be present will be ignored as you count your whole seconds or milliseconds.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).