# Java library function for converting from gregorian timestamp to UNIX timestamp(epoch)

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I am getting a variable with Gregorian seconds and would like to use it in Java. Is there a library function in Java <=8, JodaTime, Apache commons, guava or anything else, where this is implemented?

I know I can convert the gregorian seconds to epoch timestamp by multiplying by 1000 and then subtracting 62167219200000 but I'd prefer not to hardcode it if there already is an implementation. I haven't found any so far.

[edit: this is not a duplicate of the linked question, there's no xml dateTime used here, the answer in linked question does not answer this one]

Comment: You dont have to multiply by 1000, just subtract 62167219200
its a simple subtraction, so adding a library for that seems overhead...

Comment: we already have a huge amount of libraries added anyway so if there is an implementation in one of the common libraries, I wouldn't have to add anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4018528/1123020